# Excel feet and inches to millimeters

Tags: excel, function, math, excel-formula

I have many excel field witch contains ft and inches example: 5' 10".

How to i convert it to meters assuming the feet and inches value is on A1.

iv tried to backtrack this formula with no success

```
=INT(CONVERT(A1,"mm","ft")) & " '" &  12*(CONVERT(A1,"mm","ft")-INT(CONVERT(A1,"mm","ft"))) & """"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This formula should do it:

```
=CONVERT(LEFT(A1,FIND("'",A1)-1),"ft","m") + CONVERT(SUBSTITUTE(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND(" ",A1)),"""",""),"in","m")
```

The formula assumes both feet and inch values are in the cell even if equal to 0. For example, cell values like `0' 10"` and `5' 0"` will work, but values like `10"` or `5'` will not.

Comment: Just be careful with `;`. OP's local settings use `,`

Comment: Indeed - i'll edit the answer - i think "," is more common. Thanks!